# Generate a token every day inside a service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, token

I have to create an endpoint, which collects information and then it inserts to a BBDD. The problem is to access this information, the token must always be added to the query params and it expires every 20 hours.

To get the token, firstly I have to make it a call like this one

```
https://url/token.php?username=...&password=...
```

I'll get a response like this one

```
{"success":true,"token":"aaaa","expire":1589780649}
```

An example of the endpoint to gather information would be

```
https://url/information.php?token=aaaa&fields=a,b
```

I have to say that I am new to java spring (and java in general). Is there a way to create a microservice that, before collecting the information, obtains the token every 20 hours?

Answer (score 0):

If you save token in DB, then you can check token on expiry after any request

For example:

```
if (token.getExpire > 20 hours) { 
    Token token = tokenRepository.findByToken(token);
    if (token != null) {
        generateNewToken();
        remove and save new token or change old token in DB
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it is never stored in the DB. The service made just one call per day, recollect the information, and stores it in the DB. It has to be used in the logic of the service.

Comment: Then you need to refresh token or if token expiry then return new token in response

Comment: You say inside a controller for example? Imagine a endpoint name getInformation, should I call the token service every time?

Comment: I think you can do the same, 1) do request 2) if return token expired 3) then refresh token 4)  repeat first request